# Axon Kafka Integration - Using a custom Kafka ProducerFactory

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, axon

I'm using the Kafka example from GitHub (https://github.com/marinkobabic/axon-kafka-example) and it's working when connecting to a locally deployed Kafka cluster. As suggested by Axon's [docs](http://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/3.3), I'm trying to use a custom kafka **ProducerFactory** by exposing a **KafkaPublisher** bean and overriding **withProducerFactory**(). My bean is created, but **createProducer**() of my custom kafka **ProducerFactory** is never getting called. In fact, Axon's **DefaultProducerFactory** is still used. Any suggestions?

```
@Bean
KafkaPublisher<byte[], byte[]> kafkaPublisher(ProducerFactory factory) {
    KafkaPublisherConfiguration configuration = KafkaPublisherConfiguration.<String, byte[]>builder()
        .withMessageSource(new SimpleEventBus())
        .withProducerFactory(new org.axonframework.kafka.eventhandling.producer.ProducerFactory<String, byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public Producer<String, byte[]> createProducer() {
                return factory.createProducer();
            }

            @Override
            public void shutDown() {
            }
        })
        .withTopic(topic)
        .build();
    KafkaPublisher<byte[], byte[]> publisher = new KafkaPublisher<>(configuration);
    publisher.start();
    return publisher;
}
```

Comment: Hi @blackcompe, which documentation are you referencing towards? Axon's Kafka section, or documentation  tied to the sample from Marinko?
Added, the Kafka-Extension and Axon's documentation in this part uses a `DefaultProducerFactory`, whilst you're creating an anonymous class in this snippet.

Comment: @Steven: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/v/3.3/

Comment: I see you've resolved the problem at hand already, great job!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem by keeping the **KafkaPublisher**, but I needed to expose an **EventBus** bean (which I qualified in **Sender.java**) and wire up the publisher to it. I also needed to expose my own axon **ProducerFactory** that wrapped my own kafka **ProducerFactory**. My final configuration is as follows:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(KafkaAutoConfiguration.class)
class AxonConfig {

    @Value("${axon.kafka.default-topic}")
    private String topic;

    @Bean
    public org.axonframework.kafka.eventhandling.producer.ProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> producerFactory(ProducerFactory factory) {
        return new org.axonframework.kafka.eventhandling.producer.ProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public Producer<byte[], byte[]> createProducer() {
                return factory.createProducer();
            }

            @Override
            public void shutDown() {
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean("event-bus")
    EventBus eventBus() {
        return new SimpleEventBus();
    }

    @Bean
    KafkaPublisher<byte[], byte[]> kafkaPublisher(org.axonframework.kafka.eventhandling.producer.ProducerFactory factory, EventBus eventBus) {
        KafkaPublisherConfiguration configuration = KafkaPublisherConfiguration.<String, byte[]>builder()
            .withMessageSource(eventBus)
            .withProducerFactory(factory)
            .withTopic(topic)
            .build();
        MyKafkaPublisher<byte[], byte[]> publisher = new MyKafkaPublisher<>(configuration);
        eventBus.subscribe((events) -> publisher.sendEvents(events));
        publisher.start();
        return publisher;
    }
}
```